# Why does html fieldset element did not work correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a page which renders four textboxes.  The top three textboxes should be grouped logically as engine settings.  Thus, I used `<fieldset>` tag to group the controls accordingly.  However, it appears that `<fieldset>` display a horizontal line beneath the `<legend>` "Engine Settings" text (screenshot below).

I wonder why it didn't work? Did I miss something in my html or style rule definition? Also, I couldn't find any related issue in SO.  I'm a newbie in HTML and CSS so please bear with me.

[image]

Snippet of html elements in my page with style rules which I have defined for the `<fieldset>` element.

```css
.hm-property {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hm-fieldset {
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 505px;
  height: 175px;
}

.hm-legend {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="hm-editorslist">
  <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Heatmap Engine Editors:</label><select class="hm-fieldItemBig" id="hmeditorcbo"></select>
  <div class="hm-EditorAdd glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="btnNewHMEditor" title="Add New Heatmap Engine Editor"></div>
  <div class="hm-EditorRemove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="btnDeleteHMEditor" title="Remove Selected Heatmap Engine Editor"></div>
  <span class="alert-info pageAlertBox LoadHMTemplate-info" style="display:none;"><strong>Loading.....</strong></span>
  <div>
    <fieldset class="hm-fieldset">
      <legend class="hm-legend">Engine Settings:</legend>
      <!--Engine Destination Folder textbox-->
      <div class="hm-property">
        <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Destination Folder:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmEngineDestFolder" title="The relative destination path of engine" />
      </div>

      <!--Engine Integrity Refresh Rate textbox-->
      <div class="hm-property">
        <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Integrity Refresh Rate:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmEngineIntegrityRate" title="Engine's integrity refresh rate (in minutes)" />
      </div>

      <!--Engine Source Folder textbox-->
      <div class="hm-property">
        <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Source Folder Path:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmSourceFolder" title="The relative source path of engine" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <!--GUI File Location textbox-->
  <div class="hm-property">
    <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">GUI File Location Path:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmGUIFileLoc" title="Relative folder path to the file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without using any stylesheets, the fieldset is displayed properly. Just tested with the CSS provided. May I know what external stylesheets you are using in your page?

Comment: @Xufox, expected result should be like this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset  Similar to a groupbox in windows form.  The problem is that it didn't display as it should be.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM that's what I thought about it, `<fieldset>` tag should display with the border around it without any style rules.  But, it didn't do that in my case.  Other external stylesheets that I'm using is from bootstrap. 
I guess other style rules have override the `<fieldset>` element.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap will overwrite the style of fieldset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With boostrap included, you can change the styles to the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
 .hm-property {
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .hm-fieldset {
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 505px;
  height: 175px;
  border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px !important;
 }

 .hm-legend {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: auto;
 }
</style>

<div class="hm-editorslist">
 <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Heatmap Engine Editors:</label>
 <select class="hm-fieldItemBig" id="hmeditorcbo"></select>
 <div class="hm-EditorAdd glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="btnNewHMEditor" title="Add New Heatmap Engine Editor"></div>
 <div class="hm-EditorRemove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="btnDeleteHMEditor" title="Remove Selected Heatmap Engine Editor"></div>
 <span class="alert-info pageAlertBox LoadHMTemplate-info" style="display:none;"><strong>Loading.....</strong></span>
 <div>
  <fieldset class="hm-fieldset">
   <legend class="hm-legend">Engine Settings:</legend>
   <!--Engine Destination Folder textbox-->
   <div class="hm-property">
    <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Destination Folder:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmEngineDestFolder"
     title="The relative destination path of engine" />
   </div>

   <!--Engine Integrity Refresh Rate textbox-->
   <div class="hm-property">
    <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Integrity Refresh Rate:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes"
     id="hmEngineIntegrityRate" title="Engine's integrity refresh rate (in minutes)" />
   </div>

   <!--Engine Source Folder textbox-->
   <div class="hm-property">
    <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">Source Folder Path:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmSourceFolder"
     title="The relative source path of engine" />
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </div>

 <!--GUI File Location textbox-->
 <div class="hm-property">
  <label class="hm-fieldItemLabel">GUI File Location Path:</label><input type="text" class="hm-textboxes" id="hmGUIFileLoc"
   title="Relative folder path to the file" />
 </div>
</div>
```